# If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, if $N(T) \cap R(T) = \{0\}$, then is it true that $V = N(T)\oplus R(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This question is already asked before in this site, but they say this is yes and also they have proved it.

But I doubt,this is even true or not.

Take , $T:\mathbb{C}^{2} \to \mathbb{C}^{2} $ such that $T(x,y)=(x+iy,x+iy)$

Clearly , $N(T)=span\{(-i,1)\}$

And, $R(T)=span\{(1,1)\}$

$N(T)\cap R(T)= \{(0,0)\}$

But $N(T) + R(T) \neq \mathbb{C}^{2}$

So, am I correct?

Or, I missed something.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not correct, since $N(T)\oplus R(T)=\Bbb C^2$. That's so because $\dim\Bbb C^2=2$, and therefore, since the set $\{(-i,1),(1,1)\}$ is linearly independent, it is a basis of $\Bbb C^2$. So, every element of $\Bbb C^2$ is a linear combination of $(-i,1)$ and $(1,1)$.

Or you can show it directly: if $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2$, then there are complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha(-i,1)+\beta(1,1)=(x,y)$; just take$$\alpha=\left(-\frac12+\frac i2\right)(x-y)\quad\text{and}\quad\beta=\left(\frac12+\frac i2\right)(-ix+y).$$

Comment: I have seen in a book that says nullspace and range space of this matrix $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & i \\
    1 & i \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ are not orthogonal complement of each other. Then why they say this?

Comment: What has that to do with this question? This question about whether or not the whole space is the direct sum of the nullspace and range. It has nothing to do with being orthogonal.

Comment: $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ are complements, just not *orthogonal* complements.

Comment: I relate this question , because $N(T) \oplus R(T)= \mathbb{C}^{2}$ then $N(T) $ and $R(T) $ are orthogonal complement to each other in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ . Right??

Comment: Wrong. In $\Bbb R^2$, with its usual inner product, $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb R(1,0)\oplus\Bbb R(1,1)$, but $\Bbb R(1,0)$ and $\Bbb R(1,1)$ are **not** orthogonal.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos oh, sorry! Now I understand where I mistake. Thank you!